# Is there a version of tuples without duplicates?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

A set is a list of elements that is unordered and does not permit duplicates, so:

$$\{1,2\} = \{2,1\}$$
$$\{1,2\} = \{1,2,2\}$$

A bag or multiset is unordered, but it allows duplicates, so:
$$[1,2]=[2,1]$$
$$[1,2]\neq[1,2,2]$$

Finally, a tuple or vector is ordered, and allows duplicates:
$$(1,2) \neq (2,1)$$
$$(1,2) \neq (1,2,2)$$

But what type of collection is ordered, but doesn't allow duplicates? For now I'll denote it with angle brackets:

$$\langle1,2\rangle \neq \langle2,1\rangle$$
$$\langle1,2\rangle =  \langle1,2,2\rangle$$

Is this type of collection ever studied in mathematics? Does it have operators?   And what is called?

Comment: [Configurations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space_(mathematics))?

Comment: Do you want $\langle2,1,2\rangle$ to be equal to $\langle1,2\rangle$ or to $\langle2,1\rangle$ or to neither. (It can't equal both since $\langle1,2\rangle\neq\langle2,1\rangle$.)

Comment: They don't have a name or theory. "Ordered set" is probably most natural, but it's sometimes used for partial or total orders. Maybe best to call them injections from $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ to a given finite set. In that guise counting them is one part of the [twelvefold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way#Injective_functions_from_N_to_X).